# How can I get touch position in scrollViewDidScroll method?

Tags: iphone, ios

I try to get touch position when I scroll the screen.
I try to get it from touchBegin() but I can't.
That's because touchBegin never called during scroll.
How can I solve this problem???
Quickly Answer to me.

Comment: Content size is bigger than my view frame, I can't enter touchesBegan method. Because of scrollViewDidScroll method called and hook touchesBegan method. So I can't get touches position in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my self it solution.

First, I set the scrollView.contentSize to scrollView.frame. so it can't call scrollViewDidScroll

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    ....
    self.frame = frame
    self.contentSize = frame;
    ....
}
```

Second, when touchesBegan set the scrollView.contentSize what I want. then the event will go to scrollViewDidScroll. You can act something.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      ....
    self.contentSize = myView.frame.size;
      ....
}
```

Thrid, in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating set the contentSize and save the contentOffest;

```
-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint pointTemp = self.contentOffset;
    self.contentSize = self.frame.size;
    self.contentOffset = pointTemp;
}
```

This will be pathetic way. If you know other, please teach me

Answer (score 3):

using the scrollview gesture recognizer :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint positionInView = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:myView];
}
```